# Why a string in the url is getting changed by few characters after sending the GET request?

Tags: java, json, servlets, http-get

**Background:**

I am trying to use [one-api](http://oneapi-gw.gsma.com/), to send SMS to phones and receive the delivery status. I make a `POST` request to their servers. Then I extract a string from the `JSON` response I receive. I use that string to make another `GET` request to a URL containing that ID. The problem is that the string gets changed when I make the `GET` request. Although it is same when I extract it from the response, but have no idea why its changing during the course of GET request.

**Methodology followed and problem explanation:**

The response from initial `POST` request` :

```
{"resourceReference":
     {"resourceURL":"https:\/\/oneapi-gw.gsma.com:443\/SendSmsService\/OneAPI_REST_v2_0\/routing\/2_0\/smsmessaging\/outbound\/tel:7511\/requests\/998371119"}
}
```

I extract the `ID` that I receive in the url(998371119). I use `.split` to extract as follows:

```
String tmp = (String)resourceReference.get("resourceURL");
String [] tmp2 = tmp.split("/");
String id = tmp2[(tmp2.length)-1].toString(); 
System.out.println(id); 
// the output is:998371119.
```

Using this ID I create another url to send a GET request.

```
String url2 = "https://oneapi-gw.gsma.com/smssend/2_0/smsmessaging/outbound/tel:7511/requests/"+id+"/deliveryInfos"
```

When I send the `GET` request, the last 2 digits of ID seems to change automatically and I receive the `Response Code` as `400` after making a GET request. Following is the error stream:

```
    {  "requestError" : 
        {    "serviceException" : { 
                 "text" : "Invalid input value for message part requestIdentifier",
                 "variables" : [ 
                     "requestIdentifier", "998371122" 
                  ]    
              }
        }
    }
```

Notice how the server interpreted the ID as `998371122` instead of `998371119`(my initial requested one). That last 2 digit changed. I've thought a lot but I've no idea why it is happening. Although when I am using `curl` to send the `GET` request, everything works fine. So it isn't a server issue. Their is some problem in either How I form the url or extract the ID or make a GET request. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**Other Relevant code you might need**

This is how I'm making a `GET` request:

```
private String getResponseFromGETRequest(String accept, String url) {

    URL obj;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();;
    HttpURLConnection con;
    String authHeaderValue = new String(Base64.encode(credentials.getBytes()));
    //Credentals variable is a string storing "username:password"
    try {
        obj = new URL(url);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + authHeaderValue);

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty ("Accept", accept);
        //con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", accept);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        InputStream ipStream;
        if (con.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
            ipStream = con.getErrorStream();
        } else {
            ipStream = con.getInputStream();
        }

        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(ipStream));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }

    return response.toString();
}
```

Logcat:

```
Oct 04, 2013 3:59:07 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection plainConnect
FINEST: ProxySelector Request for https://oneapi-gw.gsma.com/smssend/2_0/smsmessaging/outbound/tel%3A7511/requests
Oct 04, 2013 3:59:07 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection plainConnect
FINEST: Proxy used: DIRECT
Oct 04, 2013 3:59:08 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection writeRequests
FINE: sun.net.www.MessageHeader@7f47e35410 pairs: {POST /smssend/2_0/smsmessaging/outbound/tel%3A7511/requests HTTP/1.1: null}{Authorization: Basic ABCDEFGHMYAUTHORIZATIONKEY=}{Accept: application/json}{Content-Type: application/json}{Cache-Control: no-cache}{Pragma: no-cache}{User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_21}{Host: oneapi-gw.gsma.com}{Connection: keep-alive}{Content-Length: 212}
Oct 04, 2013 3:59:08 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection getInputStream
FINE: sun.net.www.MessageHeader@75240d4a17 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 201 Created}{Date: Fri, 04 Oct 2013 19:59:08 GMT}{Server: Jetty(6.1.x)}{Content-Type: application/json}{Location: https://oneapi-gw.gsma.com:443/SendSmsService/OneAPI_REST_v2_0/routing/2_0/smsmessaging/outbound/tel:7511/requests/998380556}{Host: oneapi-gw.gsma.com}{X-Forwarded-Server: oneapi-gw.gsma.com}{Authorization: Basic ABCDEFGHMYAUTHORIZATIONKEY=}{User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_21}{Accept: application/json}{X-Forwarded-For: 10.90.24.132}{X-Forwarded-Host: oneapi-gw.gsma.com}{breadcrumbId: ID-dtx-prod-apihr01-39903-1371168975552-0-440221}{Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent}{Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100}{Connection: Keep-Alive}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}

Oct 04, 2013 3:59:08 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection plainConnect
FINEST: ProxySelector Request for https://oneapi-gw.gsma.com/smssend/2_0/smsmessaging/outbound/tel:7511/requests/998380556/deliveryInfos
Oct 04, 2013 3:59:08 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection plainConnect
FINEST: Proxy used: DIRECT
Oct 04, 2013 3:59:08 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection writeRequests
FINE: sun.net.www.MessageHeader@71d198cb9 pairs: {GET /smssend/2_0/smsmessaging/outbound/tel:7511/requests/998380556/deliveryInfos HTTP/1.1: null}{Authorization: Basic ABCDEFGHMYAUTHORIZATIONKEY=}{Accept: application/json}{Content-Type: application/json}{Cache-Control: no-cache}{Pragma: no-cache}{User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_21}{Host: oneapi-gw.gsma.com}{Connection: keep-alive}
Oct 04, 2013 3:59:08 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection getInputStream
FINE: sun.net.www.MessageHeader@778671cd15 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request}{Date: Fri, 04 Oct 2013 19:59:09 GMT}{Server: Jetty(6.1.x)}{Content-Type: application/json}{Accept: application/json}{Host: oneapi-gw.gsma.com}{breadcrumbId: ID-dtx-prod-apihr02-48223-1371168511818-0-440001}{X-Forwarded-Host: oneapi-gw.gsma.com}{X-Forwarded-For: 10.90.24.132}{User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_21}{X-Forwarded-Server: oneapi-gw.gsma.com}{Authorization: Basic ABCDEFGHMYAUTHORIZATIONKEY=}{Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent}{Connection: close}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}
Header: Date : Fri, 04 Oct 2013 19:59:09 GMT
Header: Server : Jetty(6.1.x)
Header: Content-Type : application/json
Header: Accept : application/json
Header: Host : oneapi-gw.gsma.com
Header: breadcrumbId : ID-dtx-prod-apihr02-48223-1371168511818-0-440001
Header: X-Forwarded-Host : oneapi-gw.gsma.com
Header: X-Forwarded-For : 10.90.24.132
Header: User-Agent : Java/1.7.0_21
Header: X-Forwarded-Server : oneapi-gw.gsma.com
Header: Authorization : Basic ABCDEFGHMYAUTHORIZATIONKEY=
Header: Vary : Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Header: Connection : close
Header: Transfer-Encoding : chunked
Response Code : 400
{
  "requestError" : {
    "serviceException" : {
      "messageId" : "SVC0002",
      "text" : "Invalid input value for message part requestIdentifier",
      "variables" : [ "requestIdentifier", "998380559" ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Comment: Did you try using a tool like [TCPMon](http://technonstop.com/tcpmon-tutorial) to check what's actually going on the wire?

Comment: @Hippo: That's a good idea. I'll try that tool and see what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: @Hippo: I've posted the LogCat. All the GET/POST request are going fine. It seems something on the server side. I posed what worked for me. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after two days it was a strange solution. It turns out parsing was fine and so was the formation of `GET` and `POST` request. I just kept 3 seconds delay after I received the response from `POST` request and before I sent another `GET` request. This solved it.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```